# Chrome extensions (can't get and click elements on new chrome tabs)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, paypal

That's it. Lemme explaim myself.
I coded a chrome extension that when clicking on a button, it will open a new resized tab (a paypal login) , but I can't manage to click the "log in button" of paypal because trying to

```
document.getElementById('btnLogin').click();
```

isn't working, neither adding that:

```
var paypal = window.open("https://www.paypal.com/es/signin", "PayPal", "width=400,height=400,location=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,titilebar=yes,resizable=yes");
paypal.onload = function() {
    paypal.document.getElementById('btnLogin').click();
}
```

Check out all of my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Zapatillao",
    "description": "Yatusabe te cojo sapatilla",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon128.jpg"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "chrome://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
document.getElementById('paypal_prelog').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: "paypal_prelog.js"
    });
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Discord: Loan#2334</h1>
        <button id='paypal_prelog'>PayPal Prelogin</button>
        <script src='content.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**paypal_prelog.js**

```
function sleep (ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var paypal = window.open("https://www.paypal.com/es/signin", "PayPal", "width=400,height=400,location=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,titilebar=yes,resizable=yes");
paypal.onload = function() {
    paypal.document.getElementById('btnLogin').click();
}

function closeWin() {
    paypal.close();
}
```

> I have tried thousand of things, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for a ManifestV2 extension, which you are writing, in short, is to open a new paypal sign-in window using [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) and then use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-executeScript) to inject a content script code that clicks `btnLogin` . Your current code does it all wrong though.

1. Remove `content_scripts`, `tabs`, and `chrome://*/*` from manifest.json.
2. Remove `content.js` from your extension and popup.html
3. Remove `paypal_prelog.js`
4. Create `popup.js`

   ```js
   document.getElementById('paypal_prelog').onclick = () => {
     chrome.windows.create({
       url: 'https://www.paypal.com/es/signin',
       width: 400,
       height: 400,
     }, w => {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(w.tabs[0].id, {
         code: `(${() => {
           document.getElementById('btnLogin').click();
         }})()`,
       });
     });
   };
   ```

- load popup.js in popup.html:

  ```html
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: how do I add more code lines after the "document.getElementById....." with timers? I mean, I want to do what is already done. wait and then, keep searching for elements. Tried creating a wait function and using it there, but isn't working, and all code after that nonworking function will neither work.